# Cannot Overriding Class HttpRequest Method dispatch in web module?

Tags: python, odoo, overriding, openerp-7

Iam trying to override a method inside web=>http.py file in openerp project .
I have write this code :

```
#in my_http.py 
from openerp.addons import web
class my_httprequest(web.http.HttpRequest):
    def dispatch(self, method):
        #some new code here ...
```

but will not overriding the original ? 
where is the problem , why cannot override ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the 'my_http.py' statement in '**openerp**.py' file ?

Comment: no , i put it in __init__.py file "import my_http" ?should i ? how do that ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Just a little simple question, does your module is installed ?

Comment: Yes , installed ... ?